# in C++ how can I pass a static array to an object as a parameter, and modify the original array in there?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, reference, parameter-passing

The array has to be **on the stack**, and I need to modify the elements. Here is what I have:

```
    Class Me {
private:
    int *_array;
    void run(){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i) {
            _array[i] += 100;
        }
    }
public:
    Me(int array[]) {
        _array = array;
    }
};
```

This is main:

```
    int array[10] = {0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    Me m(array);
    m.run();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

I thought array passing are done by reference, so whatever I did in run(), the array in main() should carry the result as well, but I'm obviously wrong. Any hint of what I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: For a start, this code won't even slightly compile (for instance, you've declared `Me::run` as private).  Please post actual code.

Comment: do you have `#define public private` and `#define private public` and `#define Class class` somewhere in your codebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I fix your code so that it actually compiles, I get the output

```
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
```

Is this not what you expected?

Comment: yes, it is. There were some bugs in my code, and I thought I forgot about how I could use array parameters. your answer just helped me realizing I did something else wrong. thank you!